# Getting orders by property in Commerce 2 from Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, plugin-craftcommerce2

In Commerce 1 i can select orders by a specific property as follows:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Order');
$criteria['orderStatusId'] = 1;
return craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Order', $criteria);
```

How can i do this in Commerce 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;

$products = Product::find()->orderStatus(1)->all();
```